# Continue without ssl certificate

Tags: http, ssl, https, cpanel

I have a site kismetit.com . It's ssl certificate got expired two days before.
But my site is showing

> Your connection is not secure

Now I wanna continue without ssl. So I deleted my ssl certificate. But it's not working. I checked my redirects. I didn't find any issue to solve my problem.
What should I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to get to the http version of your site, or is it still showing https? Do you get this message with different browsers?

Comment: Nothing is known about the configuration of your site. If it was it is very likely that this question would be marked as duplicate of others. My guess is that your previous redirect was either permanent (i.e. 301) and is thus cached by browsers or that you had/have a HSTS header set.

Comment: Now I can access wordrpss/wp-admin but can't uploading theme, so I manually uploaded. Even my site shows https:// if I use http:// it redirecting to https:// and shows the error message. I changed all the https:// to http:// from mysql and theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clearing the browser cookies,now it's working.